# Navigating html directories with swig templating engine?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, swig-template

I have 2 different directories inside one directory.  The first is `views` which contains all swig views such as `newpost.html`.  The other is `temp_images` which contains `butterfly.png`.

Within `newpost.html` I have,

```
<div id="image">{{post.image}}</div> <!-- this prints `butterfly.png`-->
<img src="../temp_images/{{post.image}}"></img> <!-- shows broken img link-->
```

Swig prints the text, but it will not show the butterfly.  I have no idea why and I double checked the HTML.  I also tried

```
<img src="../temp_images/butterfly.png"></img>
```

And that didn't work either.  Could there be a problem with how I'm using Swig? I'm also using Node, Express, Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express, then you should probably have your `/temp_images` directory inside of `public` or whatever you have set up to serve static files. For example, in your app.js, you should have a line like this somewhere:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 60*60*1000 }));
```

You can find more information about `.static` on the ConnectJS site, since Express gets this from Connect. [Connect.static doc](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html). `maxAge` provides a caching directive to the browser, in this case that the file is good for an hour.

Your `views` directory is typically only being accessed via your template engine and wouldn't (shouldn't) be directly exposed for static downloads.

Also note that your URL for the image is interpreted relative to the URL being displayed at the browser, not relative to the file be rendered on the server (though they could be perfectly parallel structures). I just mention it - you could look at the network section of your browser's developer tools to see the exact GET request it is making for the image.

Comment: Of COURSE!!! THank u!  Is that the way this generally works?  If I want the client to be able to upload images, I save them into a `temp_images` directory, and then use a link?  (I know that's a broad follow up) Also what is `{ maxAge: 60*60*1000 }`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'this' is in the "Is that the way this generally works?" but, yes, you could have files get uploaded (you'll probably want something like [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for parsing file uploads.) and if the destination for your files is somewhere inside your public structure, you could then just make a link to them like any other image. Could also you a different dir and a symlink from public, etc. See answer update for maxAge.